# Back out CI or SE for estimates of group means from t.test

Tags: r

I would to try to back out the standard error for the estimates of the mean from a series of nested t.tests in my data set.

Am I right that I can just take `conf.high-conf.low` and that is the confidence interval for the *difference in means*. I sort of think I can then divide that by 1.96 and that would provide the standard error from which I could calculate the CI for the estimate of each group mean, but I am not sure.

I could obviously calculate the SEs for each grouping level but a reviewer would like to see a notation for significance tests, so that's why I'm turning to running t.test on my nesting variable.

```
var1<-sample(c(2005, 2010, 2015), size=1000, replace=T)
var2<-rnorm(n=1000, mean=1, sd=0.2)
var3<-sample(c("A", "B"), size=1000, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df %>% 
  nest(-var1) %>% 
  mutate(model=map(data, function(x) t.test(var2~factor(var3), data=x))) %>% 
  mutate(tidied=map(model, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>% 
  #Back out the CI for the estimates from the CI for the interval?
  mutate(CI=conf.high-conf.low) %>% 
  mutate(SE=CI/1.96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure you describe would get you approximately the standard error of the *difference* (1.96 would be the numerator in the limit, but depending on the degrees of freedom, `qt(.975, df)` where `df` is the degrees of freedom might differ slightly.  The standard error of the difference is not just the standard error of each group.  Assuming that the two variances are not equal (the default in `t.test()`), the standard error of the difference is:

[image]

It is impossible to back out each individual group standard error if you only know the standard error of the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I had a hunch this would not work. in the end I ran the two procedures (t.test to get p-values and a a group averaging procedure with point estimates and CIs ) and then merged them together. It wasn't that hard in the end and I got what I needed. Thank you for clarifying.